# Nutch: get every url's seed url

Tags: java, nutch, web-crawler

I try to configure Nutch as an image crawler and already could get the image urls after crawl.
Now, I want to get the seed url of each image url, how can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate linkdb (inverted index) from the crawled segments and you might get the urls' parents. If there url has one parent, then it will be the seed of that url.
Read [this](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/nutch-0.8-dev/bin/nutch_invertlinks) and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/nutch-0.8-dev/bin/nutch_readlinkdb) for help on commands.